# Change your code from `jumpToIndex(2)` to `jumpTo('').` React Navigation

Tags: react-native

I provide tab control with React-navigation. I can switch between tabs in a sliding way, but when I click on the plate, it does not switch. When I click on the first plate, the tabs do not open on the second and third clicks. I am getting the following problem.

> Method `jumpToIndex` is deprecated. Please upgrade your code to use
>   `jumpTo` instead. Change your code from `jumpToIndex(7)` to
>   `jumpTo('Magazin')

```
import { TabNavigator, TabBarBottom, TabBarTop } from 'react-navigation'; 
export default (TabNavigator)(
  {
              Genel: { screen: HomeScreen },
        Magazin: { screen: MagazinScreen },
 ...

  },
   navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({

      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;

        if (routeName === 'Türkiye') {
          iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        }
        else if (routeName === 'Gündem') {
          iconName = `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        } 
}
 return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },


    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [deprecated components](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4297#issuecomment-391707953). As of react-navigation v4, the project has been splitted into subprojects.

Follow the official guide for `react-navigation` [v4](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/tab-based-navigation) or [v5](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/) on how to implement tab navigation.